# Close button to remove all classes on a div and hides when all those divs has no .extra class

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to make a script, I'm new to jQuery and still learning.

But I wanted to ask how to make this code work,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if($(".divs").hasClass('extra'))
    {
        $(".close-divs-button").css('display', 'none');
      }
      else
      {
        $(".close-divs-button").css('display', 'block');
    }

});
```

I have several Divs that when it is clicked, it adds a .extra class to expand that DIV.

I also want the .close-divs-button to only show when atleast 3 or more DIVS has a .EXTRA class in it so the user won't have to toggle the class and remove .extra by clicking them one by one, I wanted to add a button to have that global close function.

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the html sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and added pretty much all of the logic. What you want to do is check the element count with javascript `.length` property as previously stated, though, I assume you want to close elements when there are *more* than three, not exactly three of them.
So, the logic there would be

```
 if($(".extra").length > 2){
     $(".close-divs-button").show();   
 }else{
     $(".close-divs-button").hide();
 }
```

Here's a fiddle with the example I mentioned - http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/wgcmn/.

Comment: ^ THIS. Thank you so much for the effort.

Comment: Any difference, did you find in the answer I posted before this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic will goes some thing like this..

```
if($('div.extra').length >= 3)
{
   $(".close-divs-button").show();
}else{
   $(".close-divs-button").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of elements which have a class of 'extra':

```
var x = $('.extra').length;
if(x == 3)
{
    // logic goes here
}
```